# htaccess ReWriteRule to new domain

Tags: .htaccess

Writing some regular expressions for an .htaccess file. Got the second half working but the first half is driving me nuts. Any regular expression gurus wanna lend a hand?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (*./) www.domain1.com/ [R=301,L] # This is not working
RewriteRule (.*) $1.domain2.com/ [R=301,L] # This is working
</IfModule>
```

What I want is for all urls like: www. test .com/example to go to example. domain2 .com/ (This part IS working).

But I also want the main url of www. test .com/ to go to www. domain1 .com/ (This part is NOT working).

I know it's right in front of my face, but it's been a long day and I am having a brain fart).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first regex in that the search (*./) is off.  I think it should be (.*/).

Something like this

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Should redirect requests to the new-domain.

For more information I would check out this site for htaccess help http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#redirects and this for quick regex test usage this http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your rules with this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ www.domain1.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://$1.domain2.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hahaha that's not necessary - glad to hear it worked though :) You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Also, er, I suggest editing your comment and removing your email ID in case someone decides to email you and claim something :P or add you to a spam list or whatever else.